# Insert data to database using Apache storm while making sure parent entity loaded first before child entities

Tags: sql, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am trying to load data from Apache Kafka to SQL Server database. Apache Kafka has separate topics for parent and child entities along with data. I have managed to load data from Kafka to SQL Server parallelly for all entities, by creating spouts and bolts for all entities. But that results in null values for child entities as some child records gets loaded before parent entities.

Why does it append? and how can I solve it?

PS: I am using Apache Storm 0.10 and Apache Kafka 0.80

Comment: In order to have ordering with Kafka, you'd have to use the same topic for both, parents and children. Moreover, you'd have to use the same partition within that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could queries for the parent entities before inserting children. If parent is not inserted yet, delay inserting the child until the parent is available.

Comment: Yes thats one way.  But isn't there any ways that to instruct storm to load parents first and child later??